# Consuming REST API with Android

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

I'm pretty new to this, so I followed the following tutorial: [Android: Consuming a Remote JSON API with Volley](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-consuming-a-remote-json-api-with-volley/)

I was able to fetch the data from my API, but the resource I'm fetching is a bit more complex and I don't know how to handle it.

Here is the JSON I get:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "image":"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/600\/600\/technics",
         "user":{
            "data":{
               "id":"667636906616952",
               "first_name":"Lowell",
               "last_name":"Leuschke",
               "email":"Esmeralda.Hessel@hotmail.com",
               "joined":{
                  "date":"2015-10-09 15:03:19",
                  "timezone_type":3,
                  "timezone":"UTC"
               }
            }
         },
         "location":{
            "data":{
               "id":"249795421882013",
               "name":"Wedding planner EV",
               "type":"193705277324704",
               "lat":"42.69649",
               "lng":"23.32601"
            }
         },
         "tags":{
            "data":[

            ]
         },
         "likes":{
            "data":[

            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the `Post` resource. The method I have for fetching is the same as the tutorial and here is the `parse` method:

```
private List<Post> parse(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<Post> records = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray jsonPosts = json.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonPost = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = jsonPost.getString("id");
        String image = jsonPost.getString("image");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        final User user = gson.fromJson(jsonPost.getString("user"), User.class);
        final Location location = gson.fromJson(jsonPost.getString("location"), Location.class);
        Integer likes = jsonPost.getJSONObject("likes").getJSONArray("data").length();

        Post record = new Post(id, image, user, location, likes);
        records.add(record);
    }

    return records;
}
```

These are the following classes I have.

`User`:

```
public class User {

    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    ApiDate joined;


    public User(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, ApiDate joined) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.joined = joined;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public ApiDate getJoined() {
        return joined;
    }

    public String getPictureUrl() {
        return "https://graph.facebook.com/" + this.getId() + "/picture?type=normal";
    }
}
```

`Location`:

```
public class Location {
    String id;
    String name;
    String type;
    String lat;
    String lng;

    public Location(String id, String name, String type, String lat, String lng) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
}
```

And `Post`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Post {

    String id;
    String image;
    User user;
    Location location;
    ArrayList<User> tags;
    Integer likes;

    public Post(String id, String image, User user, Location location, Integer likes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.user = user;
        this.location = location;
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }


    public Integer getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }
}
```

The problem is that in this `fetch` method the `User` and the `Location` are not set properly. I believe there's the mistake, but I don't know how to handle this situation. After this I have a `PostsAdapter` with things like:

`NetworkImageView profilePicture = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);`

and then:

`profilePicture.setImageUrl(post.getUser().getPictureUrl(), userPictureLoader);`

but `post.getUser().getPictureUrl()` seems to be empty.

As requested:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
        "http://my.rest.api/api/posts",
        null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                try {
                    List<Post> posts = parse(jsonObject);

                    mAdapter.swapPostRecords(posts);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to parse data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("PH_DEBUG:", "Unable to parse data: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("PH_DEBUG:", "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage());
            }
        });

VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

Comment: Did you try using Android Studio debugging tool ? I am sure if you try to put a break point, you will get the problem !

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are sending request via volley and the onResponse method code too !

Comment: Hi! Because inside `user` jsonobject is another jsonobject `data`, so I think your User will be null or empty. The same for location

Comment: Have you tried as my answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, because inside `user` JSONObject is another `data` JSONObject

As a result, you should use

```
final User user = gson.fromJson(jsonPost.getJSONObject("user").getString("data"), User.class);
```

instead of

```
final User user = gson.fromJson(jsonPost.getString("user"), User.class);
```

The same logic applied for your `location`.

*P/S: to avoid NPE, you should also check your JSON objects to make sure they are not null*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Ivanka, can you please tell me whether my answer worked for your question or not? IMO, when you post your question, you want people help you, then at least you should have a feedback if their answers work or not. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

there is several ways to solve it, but my suggestion is:

In you API side, when you encode a variable "image", if you are using php, try encode a url string as "urlencode" to avoid "\ /" when you encode JSON.

```
$url_encoded = urlencode($your_url_string);
```

And using "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE" as option of your JSON encode:

```
$my = json_encode($my_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

As result you probable see something like that in field "image":

```
"https%3A%2F%2Fendeavor.org.br%2profile_image.png"
```

In Android side, when you receive your JSON string, do:

```
 try {
        myURL_Image_decoded = URLDecoder.decode(my_image_url, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("URL DECODE", myURL_Image_decoded);
```

This may solve a problem with slash encode "\ /".